Where did Gomez Addams get his last name?
When the magazine comic The Addams Family was adapted for television in the 1960s, the characters were finally given first names and some fleshed-out backgrounds.  The head of the family became Gomez Addams, and was depicted as a Latin lover type of Castillian ancestry.  This Hispanic background has been retained for subsequent movies, TV series, and other adaptations.
Since Gomez is supposed to be of Spanish extraction, where did he get the obviously English surname of Addams?  Out of universe, this is clearly because the family is named for its creator, Charles Addams.  But has there ever been any in-universe explanation for the family name?  For example, did Gomez have an English ancestor in his patrilineal line?  Or did he or some ancestor of his anglicize their Spanish surname (maybe Adán?) after moving to America?

Why are there so many latino's in Argentia with German last names? It's because a person can be 1/8th latin with a paternal great grandfather with a more northern European name,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Addams

"did he or some ancestor of his anglicize their Spanish surname" — they probably wanted to avoid seeming weird in America.

@PaulD.Waite I'm not sure the Addams family would ever try to avoid seeming weird.

@DBS I think it may be more of a case that they don't realize what's weird. But perhaps names are obvious. For comparison, the Munsters are also oblivious to the weirdness of their name.

Hm, an inexplicable detail in The Addams Family ?!

His surname comes from being a descendant of Adam (and the demon-woman Lillith)

According to The Addams Family Musical, the Addams' family name goes back to time immemorial, possibly even as far back as the Stone Age.

GOMEZ: Yes! Dance my brother Fester! Time to wake the dead
(FESTER dances before The Addams Family Crypt.The gate of the crypt swings open, and the ADDAMS ANCESTORS emerge, unholy spirits from many eras and places, from the recently-departed to the very first, stone-age, Addams.)
ANCESTORS: ONCE TORN ASUNDER
DOWN SIX FEET UNDER
WE GET TO GATHER HERE
CONQUISTADOR ANCESTOR: DEAD FOR FOREVER
... [etc]
ALL (CON'T): AND FAMILY BY AND BY WHEN YOU'RE AN ADDAMS
THE STANDARD ANSWERS DON’T APPLY WHEN YOU'RE AN ADDAMS
YOU DO WHAT ADDAMS DO, OR DIE!

